# Get MD5 Checksum for Very Large Files

Tags: php, hash, md5, checksum

I've written a script that reads through all files in a directory and returns md5 hash for each file.  However, it renders nothing for a rather large file.  I assume that the interpreter has some value set for maximum processing time, and since it takes too long to get this value, it just skips along to other files.  Is there anyway to get an md5 checksum for large files through PHP? If not, could it be done through a chron job with cpanel?  I gave it a shot there but it doesn't seem that my md5sum command has ever been processed: I never get an email with the hash.  Here's the PHP I've already written.  It's a very simple code and works file for files of a reasonable size:

```
function md5_dir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                echo nl2br($file . "\n" . md5_file($file) . "\n\n");
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "a rather large file"? What is the file size?

Comment: Side note: MD5 isn't a checksum, it's a hash.  Also, it's not secure.

Comment: I foolishly assumed that the md5 tool outputs the md5 checksum. XD
I'm trying to do a 1 gig file.

Comment: faraz, what I'm saying here is that MD5 is a hash, so an MD5 tool outputs an MD5 hash value.  Checksums are something else.

Comment: I understand.  I was going to compare the result of this PHP MD5 output to the md5sum output on my computer which wouldn't return the same value, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While i couldn't reproduce it with PHP 5.2 or 5.3 with a 2GB file the issue seems to come up on 32bit PHP builds.

Even so it's not a really nice solution you could try to let the system to the hasing

```
echo system("md5sum test.txt");
```

> 46d6a7bcbcf7ae0501da341cb3bae27c  test.txt

Comment: Nothing happens when I run this.

Comment: I assume you are running Linux ? Did you try it on the console and see if it works there ? (And if not maybe the error will help you :/ )

Comment: I was running the script on a FreeBSD machine; hence, no GNU `md5sum`. Thanks for the tip. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to use escapeshellarg ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php ) if you decide to use a shell_exec() or system() call.  I.e.,

```
shell_exec('md5sum -b ' . escapeshellarg($filename));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're hitting an execution time limit or maximum execution time, PHP should be throwing an error message to that effect. Check your error logs. If you are hitting a limit, you can set the maximum values for PHP memory usage and execution time in your php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 16M
```

will set max memory usage to 16 megs. For maximum execution time:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

will set maximum execution time to 30 seconds.

Comment: [function.md5-file]: failed to open stream: Value too large for defined data type

Answer (score 2):

you could achieve it with command line

```
 shell_exec('md5sum -b '. $fileName);
```

Comment: Is it possible for you guys to leave comments when you downvote on solutions ? as stated in faraz.yashar comment the php solution did not work on large amount of data, md5sum command line does. Author says he can register cron jobs, I assume he can also run shell commands with php.

Comment: I myself have upvoted , but I presume that the downvote was because there was no explanation ( for example for the ` -b` parameter ..

Answer (score 2):

FYI....in case someone needs a fast md5()check-sum. PHP is pretty fast even with the larger files. This returns the check-sum on Linux Mint .iso (size 880MB) in 3 sec.

```
<?php
// checksum
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // get upload folder path
$file = $path."/somefolder/linux-mint.iso";  // any file
echo md5_file($file);
?>
```